# Route lines from file to persistent JMS queue: How to improve performance?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I need some help with performance tuning of a use case. In this use case the Camel route is tailing status lines in a log file and sends each line as a message to a JMS queue. I have implemented the use case like this:

```
package tests;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.sjms.SjmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class LinesToQueue {

    public static void main() throws Exception {

        final File file = new File("data/log.txt");
        final String uri = "tcp://127.0.0.1:61616";

        final BrokerService jmsService = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI("broker:" + uri));
        jmsService.start();

        final SjmsComponent jmsComponent = new SjmsComponent();
        jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(uri));

        final Main main = new Main();
        main.bind("jms", jmsComponent);
        main.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                fromF("stream:file?fileName=%s&scanStream=true&scanStreamDelay=0", file.getAbsolutePath())
                        .routeId("LinesToQueue")
                        .to("jms:LogLines?synchronous=false");
            }
        });

        main.enableHangupSupport();
        main.run();
    }

}
```

When I run this use case with a file already filled with 1.000.000 lines the overall performance I get in the route is about 313 lines/second. This means that it takes about 55 minutes to process the file.

As some sort of reference I also have created another use case. In this use case the Camel route is tailing status lines in a log file and sends each line as a document to an Elasticsearch index. I have implemented the use case like this:

```
package tests;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class LinesToIndex {

    public static void main() throws Exception {

        final File file = new File("data/log.txt");
        final String uri = "local";

        final Main main = new Main();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                fromF("stream:file?fileName=%s&scanStream=true&scanStreamDelay=0", file.getAbsolutePath())
                        .routeId("LinesToIndex")
                        .bean(new LineConverter())
                        .toF("elasticsearch://%s?operation=INDEX&indexName=log&indexType=line", uri);
            }
        });

        main.enableHangupSupport();
        main.run();
    }

}
```

When I run this use case with a file already filled with 1.000.000 lines the overall performance I get in the route is about 8333 lines/second. This means that it takes about 2 minutes to process the file.

I understand that there is a huge difference between a JMS queue and an Elasticsearch index but how can have the JMS use case above to perform better?

**Update #1:**
It seems to be the persistence in the JMS service that is the bottleneck in my first use case above. If I disable the persistence in the JMS service then the performance in the route is about 11111 lines/second. Which persistence storage for the JMS service will give me a better performance?

Answer (score 1):

a couple of things to consider...

- ActiveMQ producer connections [are expensive](http://java.dzone.com/articles/lessons-learned-activemq), make sure you use a pooled connection factory...
- consider using the [VM transport](http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html) for an in process ActiveMQ instance
- consider using an external ActiveMQ broker over TCP (so it doesn't compete for resources with your test)
- setup/tune KahaDB or LevelDB to optimize persistent storage for your use case

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried various JMS components with and without connection pooling for this use case but to me it still seems to be that it is the persistent storage in the JMS service that is the bottleneck in this case. Removing the persistence will raise throughput from 313 lines/second to 11111 lines/second with no other changes.

Comment: non persistent is definitely faster, but I wouldn't rule out ActiveMQ if you need persistence...its capable of very fast throughput when setup properly...updated answer with a few other thoughts